# Shares - How would I disable these shares

Tags: windows-7

1.Admin$ C:\Windows, type windows with the description remote admin
2.C$ C:\, type windows with the description default share
3.D$ D:\, type windows with the description default share
4.IPC$, no folder paths assigned, type windows with the description remote IPC

I have read elsewhere that it's not necessary to delete them but.......
I'd like to understand how I would go about disabling / delete  these shared items.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Create a startup script, because these shares are always recreated during the boot.

An example script is :

```
 NET SHARE C$ /delete
 NET SHARE D$ /delete
 NET SHARE admin$ /delete
```

Put these commands in a .bat file, create a shortcut to it on the desktop (or elsewhere), then drag the shortcut to Start > All Programs > Startup to execute automatically upon login.

Please read this first http://support.microsoft.com/kb/842715/en-us - here you can find an potential issue that could happened while administrative shares are off. Some Windows services depend on it.